# Ubuntu HDD unlock password not working anymore. What can I do?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, password, format

I have a Acer Aspire E1-522 running on Ubuntu. I had its hard drive password protected and encrypted (Western Digital Black 750GB). I never changed the password but now it says wrong password, and I can't go beyond that point (can't boot).

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from DVD and format the drive. But Ubuntu would not let me access the boot menu to change the 1st boot device. (from hard drive to cd-rom). I tried all the keys from f1 to f12 arrow keys, esc key...

So I really don't care about the data in the hard drive; I just want to get my hard drive unlocked, formatting is fine with me. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Do you have access to any other OS installed besides [Ubantu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15684/ubuntu-misspellings/15687#15687) ?

Answer (score 1):

You tried all the keys? On start-up right? When the computer lets an f-command stop the boot. And then it goes to the menu.